# How to check if getline gets a blank line?

Tags: c++, string, newline, getline

I am wondering how I can check if the `getline` function, let's say on `string buffer` and `ifstream` input: **`getline(input, buffer)`**, stores a blank line?

So lets say I had:

```
Hello

How are you
```

So how could I identify based on the `string buffer` if I am dealing with a newline? I need this for formatting checking in a much more complicated file. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a language in mind?

Comment: Also getline implies that it only returns the string up to the next \n char which would mean that it doesn't

Comment: if(line.size == 0) then it was empty. Not sure what language ur talking about tho

Comment: Language is C++. And I'll give that a try Neil, thanks. I've been doing buffer == "" or buffer == " " but that just gives me random behavior.

Comment: `buffer.empty()` checks if a string is empty or not. The `std::getline` function does not put the newline into the returned buffer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "blank line" ? Do you mean a line with nothing at all on it, or is it allowed to have whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

After you get the `string buffer`, you can check:

```
if (get_trimmed_string(buffer).length == 0)
{
    // this line is a blank line, or contains only spaces/tabs
}
```

And the function to trim spaces or tabs can be something like:

```
// delete spaces/tabs in head and tail of str
string get_trimmed_string(string str)
{
    int s=str.find_first_not_of(" \t");
    int e=str.find_last_not_of(" \t");

    // if do find real content
    if (s!=-1 && e!=-1)
        return str.substr(s, e-s+1);

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to check whether it has only white space characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isBlankLine(char const* line)
{
    for ( char const* cp = line; *cp; ++cp )
    {
        if ( !isspace(*cp) ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool isBlankLine(std::string const& line)
{
   return isBlankLine(line.c_str());
}

int main()
{
   std::string s1 = "Hello";
   std::string s2 = "       ";
   std::string s3 = "How are you";

   std::cout << "Is s1 blank? " << isBlankLine(s1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Is s2 blank? " << isBlankLine(s2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Is s3 blank? " << isBlankLine(s3) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Is s1 blank? 0
Is s2 blank? 1
Is s3 blank? 0
```